# Requests: Check that the proxy has been used to make the HTTP Request

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, python-requests

I've been scratching my head the whole day yesterday about this and to my surprise, can't seem to find an easy way to check this.

I am using Python's Requests library to pass my proxy such as:

```
def make_request(url):
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.mount("http://", HTTPAdapter(max_retries=3))
        s.mount("https://", HTTPAdapter(max_retries=3))
        page = None
        d.rotate(-1) #d contains a dict of my proxies. this allows to rotate through the proxies everytime make_request is called.

        s.proxies = d[0]
        page = s.get(url, timeout=3)

        print('proxy used: ' + str(d[0]))
    return page.content
```

Problem is, I can't seem to make the request fail when the proxy is not expected to work. It seems there is always a fallback on my internet ip if the proxy is not working.
For example: I tried passing a random proxy ip like 101.101.101.101:8800 or removing the ip authentication that is needed on my proxies, the request is still passed, even though it should'nt.

I thought adding the timeout parameters when passing the request would do the trick, but obviously it didn't.

So

- Why does this happen?
- How can I check from which ip a request is being made?

Answer (score 2):

From what I have seen so far, you should use the form

```
s.get(url, proxies = d)
```

This should use the proxies in the dict `d` to make a connection.
This form allowed me to check with working proxies and non-working proxies the `status_code`

`print(s.status_code)`

I will update once I find out whether it just circulates over the proxies in the dict to match a working one, or one is able to actually select which one to be used.

**[UPDATE]**
Tried to work around the dict in proxies, to use different proxy if I wanted to. However, `proxies` must be a dict to work. So I used a dict in the form of:

`d = {"https" : 'https://' + str(proxy_ips[n].strip('\n'))}`

This seems to work and allow me to use an ip I want to. Although it seems quite dull, I hope someone might come and help!

The proxies used can be seen through:

```
requests.utils.getproxies()
```

or

```
requests.utils.get_environ_proxies(url)
```

I hope that helps, obviously quite old question, but still!